# Can we remove using cookie from laravel sanctrum?

Tags: laravel, api

Is there way to remove cookie based feature from laravel sanctum and only use Authorization Bearer token way.

As, by default it sets and check through cookie and this feature don't work when API is deployed with different server then front-end.

Comment: Do you really need to remove `web` middleware from sanctum authentication? If it fails, Sanctum just checks for Authorization header of incoming request [see docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#how-it-works-spa-authentication)

Besides that, you can authenticate user via cookie even in SPA hosted on different server and domain.

Comment: Actually, I have SPA deployed over different server and domain and I am facing issue authentication over cookie, for that, I have configured SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN and SESSION_DOMAIN , but still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is response status code? Any error message? Do you use Fortify together with Sanctum?

Comment: It returns : {"message":"Unauthenticated."}

Comment: It works fine with swagger doc and in postman, just getting above error for SPA which is deployed over different setup

Comment: If endpoints work well with Swagger and you get expected results when using Postman, then your frontend app most likely sends something wrong. However these comments lead to app debugging, not answering a question, so I will write answer and leave it up to you if you consider it as helpful answer or not.

Comment: Second thought, just stupid question. Did you configure `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN` (mentioned above) or `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` (extra trailling S, real env variable)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
`\Laravel\Sanctum\Guard` goes through config `sanctum.guard`, default value is `web`, so you can set this config in your `config/sanctum.php` file to whatever suits your need.
Eventually, you can change your `web` middleware group, if your SPA is the only GUI client.

If any of mentioned options is viable or smart is another question, to which I'd reply: "nope, configure your app properly to send and accept security headers and/or cookies with cors settings fitting your needs."